# dynamically change template by dragging with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, draggable

I have the following setup in my application:
http://plnkr.co/edit/I2RCjYU17SDX65thUUqD?p=preview

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Panel 1
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="height: 250px;">
              Panel 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Panel 2
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="height: 250px;">
              Panel 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Panel 3
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="height: 250px;">
              Panel 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="panel-title">
                    Panel 4
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="height: 250px;">
              Panel 4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

What I am trying to do is to be able to re-order the panels by dragging them.
For example, I want to be able to drag panel 1 to the bottom right and have it switch positions with panel 4.  I'm relatively new to angularjs and I have no idea how to go about tackling a problem like this.

My initial idea was to create a different template for each possible combination of panels and dynamically include the template off of a variable I set, however this would require having 16 different templates and I feel like there must be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a external dependency (Angular-dragdrop) within Angularjs. Give each canvas a sequence and reorder by sequence when you drag a canvas in an other place.

Here you find more information: http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop/#/